# Django get max length value from same model with Coalesce

Tags: django, django-orm

I'm trying to write the following raw query with the ORM. I'm not sure is it possible or not.

```sql
select first_name,
       middle_name,
       COALESCE(middle_name, (
           select middle_name
           from contacts c2
           where c2.first_name = c1.first_name
             and c2.last_name = c1.last_name
             and c2.middle_name is not null
           order by length(c2.middle_name) desc
           limit 1
       )
           ) expected,
       last_name
from contacts c1
```

The expected result is like the following, if middle_name is null, get the middle name from another record that has the same first_name and last_name.

```
id| first_name | middle_name | expected | last_name
1 | ahmet      |   <NULL>    |  burak   |   ozyurt
2 | ahmet      |   burak     |  burak   |   ozyurt
```

```py
class Contact(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
```

DB: Postgres
Django Version: 3.12

Comment: For a workaround, I have updated all the middle_name with raw SQL. I'm just curious about the solution.

Comment: Can you share the model?

Comment: @IainShelvington updated. I just tried to abstract my question. The model has other fields like address info but I didn't include those fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using the django ORM, you can perform the same query by using the following code

```py
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce, Length

matched_middle_name_queryset = Contact.objects.filter(
    first_name=models.OuterRef("first_name"),
    last_name=models.OuterRef("last_name"),
    middle_name__isnull=False,
).annotate(
    middle_name_len=Length("middle_name")
).order_by("-middle_name_len").values("middle_name")[:1]

result = Contact.objects.annotate(
    matched_middle_name=models.Subquery(matched_middle_name_queryset)
    expected=Coalesce(
        models.F("middle_name")
        models.F("matched_middle_name"),
    ).values("id", "first_name", "middle_name", "expected", "last_name")
)
```

## Explanations

1. `models.OuterRef` is used for referring to the field from the parent query of a subquery.
2. `-` prefix in the `order_by("-middle_name_len")` is for descending order
3. `.values("middle_name")` is for selecting only `middle_name` values.
4. the slicing `[:1]` is for limiting the result from the subquery to be one.

**Tips**

- You can use `result.query` to inspect what query the ORM will generate for you.

Comment: That was awesome, thanks. I'm still trying to understand the complex ORMs, this will help me a lot.